# RequireJS's asynchronous nature

Tags: javascript, requirejs

Javascript newbie so I'm guessing this is obvious, but I'm clearly missing something fundamental about RequireJS.

```js
require(['lib/someSlowLoadingLib'], function() {
    console.log('Loaded Slow Lib');
    console.log(slowLib.incByOne(10)); // shows 11
});

// References slow lib
slowLib.incByOne(10) // throws error, slowLib not found
```

How can I immediately use what's being loaded by 'require'?  If it's loaded asynchronously it's not available when I need it, which is right away.

I understand that I could put my code inside the require function which would be ok for a single dependency, but if I dependencies are deeply nested this could get messy, no?  My main code running within several anonymous functions?  If this is the way it's done that's fine but it does not seem correct.

Comment: You can't. That's the point of asynchronous. It loads things in the background while executing the rest of your script.

Comment: Thank you Mike but I understand that.  My question is, how can a dependency mgmt system function if when I need a dependency it's not guaranteed to be there. People use RequireJS heavily so clearly this problem has been solved.

Comment: If you intend to use a dependency management system, you must work within it's requirements. In this case, it is mandatory to wrap your code inside the requireJS callback function because that's it's purpose: to tell you the scripts are ready.

Comment: what you mean by several anonymous functions? you simply require all your dependencies and put all your main code in the callback func

Comment: @yngum - in my use case I actually have another module (A) that relies on someSlowLoadingLib, and my main code relies on module A.  So I'd have put my code inside the callback for A, and require A in the callback for someSlowLoadingLib.

Comment: you require someSlowLoadingLib and A then put ur main code in one callback. As for module A, it is in another file that require someSlowLoadLib, I dont see how it is messy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should place all your code that requires someSlowLoadingLib inside the callback where you're requiring it.

That is the nature of the async pattern.

Anything you place outside of that callback function must not require slowLib.

Comment: Solved this by putting the majority of the code within 'define' functions and only a kickoff function nested under 'require'.

Comment: Sounds like a perfectly valid solution. Your code is not really doing anything different, you're just organizing it better. In general, you should break up your code into functions that each do a simple task, anyway.